# Do we have Support for sending Traffic in HTTP2.0 Version in ZAProxy

Tags: http2, zap

Currently if I scan(from both UI and CLI) using ZAProxy it sends HTTPS Traffic using HTTP1.1 version, Do we have any Support or Workaround to send HTTPS Traffic using HTTP2.0 version in ZAProxy.

Any help on this is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

No [ZAProxy does not support HTTP/2 at this time](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/5038).

Comment: Do we have any workaround for ZAProxy to support HTTP2.

Comment: You might be able to use something like: https://github.com/sensepost/mallet Note: It makes it really difficult for the team to help you when you cross post the same question multiple places. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zaproxy-users/jwWlFSZMtlg

Answer (score 0):

The Paros networking layer used by ZAP is old, and lacks support of modern options such as HTTP/2. They planned to replace this but there is no ETA as of now.

refer the thread : https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/1765

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.